# how to add conditional statement to - tic - tac - toe game tie function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The problem is if all cells are taken but someone won on the last move, in tic tac toe The problem it should not return a winner. But if the last square is the winning marker, it will return the tie.

I tried adding a conditional statement, but it does not work.

```
if (emptySquares().length==0 && gameWon.player != hplayer || gameWon.player != ailayer)
```

can anyone please show me any conditional statement.

```js
class Stopwatch {
    constructor(display, results) {
        this.running = false;
        this.display = display;
        this.results = results;
        this.laps = [];
        this.reset();
        this.print(this.times);
    }
    
    reset() {
        this.times = [ 0, 0, 0 ];
    }
    
    start() {
        if (!this.time) this.time = performance.now();
        if (!this.running) {
            this.running = true;
            requestAnimationFrame(this.step.bind(this));
        }
    }
     
    restart() {
        if (!this.time) this.time = performance.now();
        if (!this.running) {
            this.running = true;
            requestAnimationFrame(this.step.bind(this));
        }
        this.reset();
    }
    
    step(timestamp) {
        if (!this.running) return;
        this.calculate(timestamp);
        this.time = timestamp;
        this.print();
        requestAnimationFrame(this.step.bind(this));
    }
    
    calculate(timestamp) {
        var diff = timestamp - this.time;
        // Hundredths of a second are 100 ms
        this.times[2] += diff / 10;
        // Seconds are 100 hundredths of a second
        if (this.times[2] >= 100) {
            this.times[1] += 1;
            this.times[2] -= 100;
        }
        // Minutes are 60 seconds
        if (this.times[1] >= 60) {
            this.times[0] += 1;
            this.times[1] -= 60;
        }
    }
    
    print() {
        this.display.innerText = this.format(this.times);
    }
    
    format(times) {
        return `\
${pad0(times[0], 2)}:\
${pad0(times[1], 2)}:\
${pad0(Math.floor(times[2]), 2)}`;
    }
}

function pad0(value, count) {
    var result = value.toString();
    for (; result.length < count; --count)
        result = '0' + result;
    return result;
}

function clearChildren(node) {
    while (node.lastChild)
        node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
}

let stopwatch = new Stopwatch(
    document.querySelector('.stopwatch'),
    document.querySelector('.results'));


// @@@ TIC_TAC_TOE @@@@

var board;
const hplayer ="0"; //human player
const aiplayer ="x"; //machine player
const wincom = // DEACLARE WINING COMBINATIONS

[
 [0,1,2],
 [3,4,5],
 [6,7,8],
 [0,3,6],
 [1,4,7],
 [2,5,8],
 [0,4,8],
 [6,4,2],
]

//GET ALL INSIDE THE CELL CLASS
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
startGame();
stopwatch.start();

var mySound; //VARIABLE FOR SOUNDS 

function startGame()
{
 // AT THE GAME END DISPLAY NONE
 document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "none";
 // CREATE ARRAYS FOR 9 BORD ELEMENTS
 board = Array.from(Array(9).keys());
 //CLEAR BOARD AFTER WINNING 
 for (var i = 0; i <cells.length; i++)
 {
  cells[i].innerText =''; // CLEAR CELLS
  cells[i].style.removeProperty('background-color'); //REMOVE WINING HIGHLIGHT COLOR FROM BOARD AND ASSIGN TO BACKGROUND COLOR
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', turnClick, false); // CALL CLICK
  mySound = new sound("bounce.mp3");
 }  
}

function turnClick(square)
{
 // GENARATE  TARGET CELL NUMBER USING HUMAN PLAYER CLICK EVENT
 //console.log(square.target.id, hplayer)

 if (typeof board[square.target.id] == 'number') {// DISABLE OTHER CELLS
   turn(square.target.id, hplayer)
   if (!checkTie()) turn(bestSpot(), aiplayer);
 }  
}

function turn(squareId, player)
{
 board[squareId] =  player; // SHOW PLAYER AND SQUARE ID WHICH IS PLAYER CLICKED
 document.getElementById(squareId).innerText = player;
 let gameWon = checkWin(board, player) //GAME WON PLAYER AND BOARD CELLS
 if (gameWon) gameOver (gameWon) // IF GAME WON CALL GAMEOVER FUNCTION WITH GAMEWON VARIABLE
}

function checkWin(board, player) 
{ 
 // TAKE ARRAY AND ADD THE INDEX TOO THE ARRAY, IDENTIFY EVERY INDEX OF PLAYER CLICKED 
 
 //check all the spots on the board played (e = elements , i = array, a = qemulator)
 let plays = board.reduce((a, e, i) =>
  (e===player) ? a.concat(i) : a, []);

 // SET GAME WON NULL DROW NO WINS 
 let gameWon = null;

 //CHECK IF GAME HAS BEEN WON
  for(let[index, win] of wincom.entries()) //GET INDEX AND WIN
  { 
   // CHECK IF THE PLAYER CLICK TO THE ANY WINING ELEMENTS IN WINING COMBINATION
   if (win.every(elem=>plays.indexOf(elem) >-1))
   {
    // WIHICH PLAYER WON ? AND WINING INDEX ?
   gameWon = {index: index, player:player};
   break; // BREAK FUNCTION
  }
 }
return gameWon; //IF WON GAME WON RETURN OR NOT RETURN GAME WON NULL
}

function gameOver(gameWon)
{
 for (let index of wincom[gameWon.index]) // INDEX OF WINNING COMBINATION WHICH PLAYER HAS CLICKED 
 {
  document.getElementById(index).style.backgroundColor = 
   gameWon.player == hplayer ? "red": "blue"; // IF THE PLAYER WHO WON HUMAN PLAYER INDEX OF WINING COMBINATIONS BECOME BLUE OR AI PLAYER INDEX BECOME RED
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) // check if available spots length is more than to 0
 {
  cells[i].removeEventListener('click', turnClick, false); // DISABLE CELLS CLICKING AFTER WINING REMOVE CLICK
 }

 declareWinner(gameWon.player == hplayer ? "YOU WON!!" : "YOU LOSS!!");
 stopwatch.running = false;
 stopwatch.time = null;
}

function declareWinner(who)
{
 document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "block";
 document.querySelector(".endgame .text").innerText = who;
}

function emptySquares()
{
 // fillter every element in the board to see if the type of the elemnts eqales to number
 return board.filter(s => typeof s == 'number'); 
 //if type of is a number return the number
}

function bestSpot()
{
 return minimax(board, aiplayer).index;
 //RETURNS THE CALLING OF MINIMAX FUNCTION PASSING BOARD AND AI PLAYER AND GET INDEX OF COMPUTER PLAYING 
}

function checkTie()
{
 if(emptySquares().length == 0) // EVERY SQUARE FILLED UP *NO WINNER*
 {
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length;i++)
  {
   cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#1a0033"; // ALL CELLS GREEN 
   cells[i].removeEventListener('click', turnClick,false);

   stopwatch.running = false;
   stopwatch.time = null;
  }

  declareWinner("Game Tie !! ")
  return true;

  }
  return false;
}

// minimax find a optimal move for player 
function minimax(newboard, player) // CREATE MINIMAX FUNCTION USING NEWBORD AND PLAYER ARGUMENT 
{                      
 var avaSpots = emptySquares(); // check available spots of the board (Empty squares)

 if (checkWin(newboard, player)) //if checking someone winning states 
 {
  return{score: -10}; // if human player wins return -10
 }
 else if (checkWin(newboard, aiplayer)) // if AI player wins return +10
  {
   return{score: 10};
  }
  else if (avaSpots.length === 0) // if no available spots(0), game tie, then return 0
  {
   return {score: 0};
  }

  var moves =[];//ARRAY MOVES to collect scores
  for(var i = 0; i < avaSpots.length; i++) // check array available spots length morethan to 0
  {
   var move  = {}; // create moves object to catch available spots
   move.index = newboard[avaSpots[i]]; //set the index number of the available spots to the move object property
   newboard[avaSpots[i]] = player; // set the available spots for the current player

   if (player == aiplayer) 
   {
    var result = minimax(newboard, hplayer); //call minimax for human player
    move.score = result.score;
   }
   else
   {
    var result = minimax (newboard, aiplayer);
    move.score = result.score;
   }

   //minimax reset newboard and push the move object to moves array
   newboard[avaSpots[i]] = move.index;
   moves.push(move);
   mySound.play();
  }
 
  // check the best move in the move arrray
 var bestMove;
 if(player === aiplayer)//should chose with the highst score when AI play 
 {
  var bestScore = -10000;
  for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++)
   {
   if (moves[i].score > bestScore) //store highst score
    {
    bestScore = moves[i].score;
    bestMove = i;
   }
  }
 }

 else
  {
   var bestScore = 10000;
   for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++)
   {
    if(moves[i].score < bestScore)
    {
     bestScore = moves[i].score; // store lowest score
     bestMove = i;
    }
   }
  }

  return moves[bestMove]; //return object store inside the bestmove
} 

function sound(src) {
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
    this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function(){
        this.sound.play();
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        this.sound.pause();
    }    
}
```

```css
body
{
 background-image: url(background.jpg);
}

table
{
  margin-top: 80px;
  background: transparent; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #393d44;
}

td
{
 height: 130px;
 width: 120px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family: "Bradley Hand ITC";
 color: red;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 70px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

table tr:first-child
{
  box-shadow:0px 8px 5px -5px blue;
}

table tr:nth-child(2)
{
  box-shadow:0px -8px 5px -5px blue
        , 0px 8px 5px -5px blue;
}

table tr:last-child
{
  box-shadow:0px -8px 5px -5px blue;  
}

table tr td:first-child
{
  box-shadow:8px 0px 5px -5px blue;  
}

table tr td:nth-child(2)
{
  box-shadow:-8px 0px 5px -5px blue
        , 8px 0px 5px -5px blue;
}

table tr td:last-child
{
  box-shadow:-8px 0px 5px -5px blue;  
}

.endgame
{
 display: none;
 width: 300px;
 top: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(70, 80, 120, 0.66);
 position: absolute;
 left: 645px;
 margin-left: -112px;
 margin-top: 10%;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #f9f1f1;
 font-background: #0C3F6F !important; 
 font-size:45px;
 font-family: monospace;
}

.button  
{
 height:35px;
 background-color: #e0f1ed2e;
 color: white;
 border:none;
 border-radius: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-size: 25px;
   transition: 0.3s;
   font-family: monospace;
 
}

.button:hover 
{
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: coral;

}

a 
{
 text-decoration-line: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.button_f
{
 height:35px;
 background-color: #e0f1ed2e;
 border:none;
 border-radius: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-size: 20px;
    background: #0C3F6F !important; 
    font-family: monospace;
    color:white !important;
}

html {
  color: #bbb;
  font-family: Menlo;
}

.stopwatch {
  font-size: 80px; 
  text-align: center;
}

.results {
  border-color: lime;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
 <!--LINK  CSS STYLESHEET-->
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tic_tac_toe.css">
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

 </head>

 <body>

<embed src="dChanyeol (EXO) & Punch - Stay With Me FMV (Goblin OST Part 1) (Eng Sub + Rom + Han).mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop ="true">

<!--BACKGROUND MUSI
<audio id="myaudio">
  <source src="music.mp3">
</audio>

 JS FOR MUSIC VOLUME
<script>
  var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio").loop=true; 
  audio.volume = 0.2;
  </script>C-->

<div class="stopwatch"></div>
  <ul class="results"></ul>

 <!--CREATE BORD FOR TIC TAC TOE GAME-->
  <table align="center">
   <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="0"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="1"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="2"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="3"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="4"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="5"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="6"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="7"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="8"></td>
   </tr>

   <!--MESSAGE CLASS FOR END GAME-->
    <div class="endgame">
     <div class="text"></div>

     
     <!--BUTTON FOR REPLAY-->
      <button onclick="startGame(), stopwatch.restart();" class="button">Restart</button> <br>
      <!--<button onclick="location.reload();" class="button">Restart New Game</button>-->
      <button class="button_f"><a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/">Share This on Facebook</a></button>
    </div> <!--END MESSAGE-->

  </table> <!--END GAME TABLE BOARD-->
   
 
   <!--LINK JAVASCRIPT-->
  <script src="tic_tac_toe.js"></script>
  

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please leave the squares to click to reproduce this issue

Comment: 3,4,9,7,8 it is a winning combination. but it shows as tie. i think its check if condition of function checkTie, and it becomes true, if (emptySquares().length === 0). thank you

Comment: check my answer

Comment: thank you for the reply. but now it doesn't show game tie.   1,3,,8,6,9

Comment: combination of 3,6,9 ( [2,5,8] )is a win right?

Comment: yes 3,5,6 is a win, problem is now game tie doesn't work.  if(emptySquares().length == 0 && !this.winner) condition becomes false when game tie.

Comment: code updated check now

Comment: thank you, but doesn't work, now winner shows. however game tie doesn't work [1,3,,8,6,9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have introduced a new boolean variable `this.winner` as false and I checked it in the `checkTie()` function. and in `gameOver()` function I made that variable true

```js
class Stopwatch {
    constructor(display, results) {
        this.running = false;
        this.display = display;
        this.results = results;
        this.laps = [];
        this.winner = false;
        this.reset();
        this.print(this.times);
    }
    
    reset() {
        this.times = [ 0, 0, 0 ];
    }
    
    start() {
        if (!this.time) this.time = performance.now();
        if (!this.running) {
            this.running = true;
            requestAnimationFrame(this.step.bind(this));
        }
    }
     
    restart() {
        if (!this.time) this.time = performance.now();
        if (!this.running) {
            this.running = true;
            requestAnimationFrame(this.step.bind(this));
        }
        this.reset();
    }
    
    step(timestamp) {
        if (!this.running) return;
        this.calculate(timestamp);
        this.time = timestamp;
        this.print();
        requestAnimationFrame(this.step.bind(this));
    }
    
    calculate(timestamp) {
        var diff = timestamp - this.time;
        // Hundredths of a second are 100 ms
        this.times[2] += diff / 10;
        // Seconds are 100 hundredths of a second
        if (this.times[2] >= 100) {
            this.times[1] += 1;
            this.times[2] -= 100;
        }
        // Minutes are 60 seconds
        if (this.times[1] >= 60) {
            this.times[0] += 1;
            this.times[1] -= 60;
        }
    }
    
    print() {
        this.display.innerText = this.format(this.times);
    }
    
    format(times) {
        return `\
${pad0(times[0], 2)}:\
${pad0(times[1], 2)}:\
${pad0(Math.floor(times[2]), 2)}`;
    }
}

function pad0(value, count) {
    var result = value.toString();
    for (; result.length < count; --count)
        result = '0' + result;
    return result;
}

function clearChildren(node) {
    while (node.lastChild)
        node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
}

let stopwatch = new Stopwatch(
    document.querySelector('.stopwatch'),
    document.querySelector('.results'));


// @@@ TIC_TAC_TOE @@@@

var board;
const hplayer ="0"; //human player
const aiplayer ="x"; //machine player
const wincom = // DEACLARE WINING COMBINATIONS

[
 [0,1,2],
 [3,4,5],
 [6,7,8],
 [0,3,6],
 [1,4,7],
 [2,5,8],
 [0,4,8],
 [6,4,2],
]

//GET ALL INSIDE THE CELL CLASS
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
startGame();
stopwatch.start();

var mySound; //VARIABLE FOR SOUNDS 

function startGame()
{
 // AT THE GAME END DISPLAY NONE
 document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "none";
 // CREATE ARRAYS FOR 9 BORD ELEMENTS
 board = Array.from(Array(9).keys());
 //CLEAR BOARD AFTER WINNING 
 for (var i = 0; i <cells.length; i++)
 {
  cells[i].innerText =''; // CLEAR CELLS
  cells[i].style.removeProperty('background-color'); //REMOVE WINING HIGHLIGHT COLOR FROM BOARD AND ASSIGN TO BACKGROUND COLOR
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', turnClick, false); // CALL CLICK
  mySound = new sound("bounce.mp3");
 }  
}

function turnClick(square)
{
 // GENARATE  TARGET CELL NUMBER USING HUMAN PLAYER CLICK EVENT
 //console.log(square.target.id, hplayer)

 if (typeof board[square.target.id] == 'number') {// DISABLE OTHER CELLS
   turn(square.target.id, hplayer)
   if (!checkTie()) turn(bestSpot(), aiplayer);
 }  
}

function turn(squareId, player)
{
 board[squareId] =  player; // SHOW PLAYER AND SQUARE ID WHICH IS PLAYER CLICKED
    if(squareId)
     document.getElementById(squareId).innerText = player;

 let gameWon = checkWin(board, player) //GAME WON PLAYER AND BOARD CELLS
 if (gameWon) {
        this.winner = true;
        gameOver (gameWon) // IF GAME WON CALL GAMEOVER FUNCTION WITH GAMEWON VARIABLE
    }
}

function checkWin(board, player) 
{ 
 // TAKE ARRAY AND ADD THE INDEX TOO THE ARRAY, IDENTIFY EVERY INDEX OF PLAYER CLICKED 
 
 //check all the spots on the board played (e = elements , i = array, a = qemulator)
 let plays = board.reduce((a, e, i) =>
  (e===player) ? a.concat(i) : a, []);

 // SET GAME WON NULL DROW NO WINS 
 let gameWon = null;

 //CHECK IF GAME HAS BEEN WON
  for(let[index, win] of wincom.entries()) //GET INDEX AND WIN
  { 
   // CHECK IF THE PLAYER CLICK TO THE ANY WINING ELEMENTS IN WINING COMBINATION
   if (win.every(elem=>plays.indexOf(elem) >-1))
   {
    // WIHICH PLAYER WON ? AND WINING INDEX ?
   gameWon = {index: index, player:player};
   break; // BREAK FUNCTION
  }
 }
return gameWon; //IF WON GAME WON RETURN OR NOT RETURN GAME WON NULL
}

function gameOver(gameWon)
{
 for (let index of wincom[gameWon.index]) // INDEX OF WINNING COMBINATION WHICH PLAYER HAS CLICKED 
 {
  document.getElementById(index).style.backgroundColor = 
   gameWon.player == hplayer ? "red": "blue"; // IF THE PLAYER WHO WON HUMAN PLAYER INDEX OF WINING COMBINATIONS BECOME BLUE OR AI PLAYER INDEX BECOME RED
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) // check if available spots length is more than to 0
 {
  cells[i].removeEventListener('click', turnClick, false); // DISABLE CELLS CLICKING AFTER WINING REMOVE CLICK
 }
 declareWinner(gameWon.player == hplayer ? "YOU WON!!" : "YOU LOSS!!");
 stopwatch.running = false;
 stopwatch.time = null;
}

function declareWinner(who)
{
 document.querySelector(".endgame").style.display = "block";
 document.querySelector(".endgame .text").innerText = who;
}

function emptySquares()
{
 // fillter every element in the board to see if the type of the elemnts eqales to number
 return board.filter(s => typeof s == 'number'); 
 //if type of is a number return the number
}

function bestSpot()
{
 return minimax(board, aiplayer).index;
 //RETURNS THE CALLING OF MINIMAX FUNCTION PASSING BOARD AND AI PLAYER AND GET INDEX OF COMPUTER PLAYING 
}

function checkTie()
{
 if(emptySquares().length == 0 && !this.winner) // EVERY SQUARE FILLED UP *NO WINNER*
 {
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length;i++)
  {
   cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "#1a0033"; // ALL CELLS GREEN 
   cells[i].removeEventListener('click', turnClick,false);

   stopwatch.running = false;
   stopwatch.time = null;
  }

  declareWinner("Game Tie !! ")
  return true;

  }
  return false;
}

// minimax find a optimal move for player 
function minimax(newboard, player) // CREATE MINIMAX FUNCTION USING NEWBORD AND PLAYER ARGUMENT 
{                      
 var avaSpots = emptySquares(); // check available spots of the board (Empty squares)

 if (checkWin(newboard, player)) //if checking someone winning states 
 {
  return{score: -10}; // if human player wins return -10
 }
 else if (checkWin(newboard, aiplayer)) // if AI player wins return +10
  {
   return{score: 10};
  }
  else if (avaSpots.length === 0) // if no available spots(0), game tie, then return 0
  {
   return {score: 0};
  }

  var moves =[];//ARRAY MOVES to collect scores
  for(var i = 0; i < avaSpots.length; i++) // check array available spots length morethan to 0
  {
   var move  = {}; // create moves object to catch available spots
   move.index = newboard[avaSpots[i]]; //set the index number of the available spots to the move object property
   newboard[avaSpots[i]] = player; // set the available spots for the current player

   if (player == aiplayer) 
   {
    var result = minimax(newboard, hplayer); //call minimax for human player
    move.score = result.score;
   }
   else
   {
    var result = minimax (newboard, aiplayer);
    move.score = result.score;
   }

   //minimax reset newboard and push the move object to moves array
   newboard[avaSpots[i]] = move.index;
   moves.push(move);
   mySound.play();
  }
 
  // check the best move in the move arrray
 var bestMove;
 if(player === aiplayer)//should chose with the highst score when AI play 
 {
  var bestScore = -10000;
  for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++)
   {
   if (moves[i].score > bestScore) //store highst score
    {
    bestScore = moves[i].score;
    bestMove = i;
   }
  }
 }

 else
  {
   var bestScore = 10000;
   for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++)
   {
    if(moves[i].score < bestScore)
    {
     bestScore = moves[i].score; // store lowest score
     bestMove = i;
    }
   }
  }

  return moves[bestMove]; //return object store inside the bestmove
} 

function sound(src) {
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
    this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function(){
        this.sound.play();
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        this.sound.pause();
    }    
}
```

```css
body
{
 background-image: url(background.jpg);
}

table
{
  margin-top: 80px;
  background: transparent; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #393d44;
}

td
{
 height: 130px;
 width: 120px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family: "Bradley Hand ITC";
 color: red;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 70px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

table tr:first-child
{
  box-shadow:0px 8px 5px -5px blue;
}

table tr:nth-child(2)
{
  box-shadow:0px -8px 5px -5px blue
        , 0px 8px 5px -5px blue;
}

table tr:last-child
{
  box-shadow:0px -8px 5px -5px blue;  
}

table tr td:first-child
{
  box-shadow:8px 0px 5px -5px blue;  
}

table tr td:nth-child(2)
{
  box-shadow:-8px 0px 5px -5px blue
        , 8px 0px 5px -5px blue;
}

table tr td:last-child
{
  box-shadow:-8px 0px 5px -5px blue;  
}

.endgame
{
 display: none;
 width: 300px;
 top: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(70, 80, 120, 0.66);
 position: absolute;
 left: 645px;
 margin-left: -112px;
 margin-top: 10%;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #f9f1f1;
 font-background: #0C3F6F !important; 
 font-size:45px;
 font-family: monospace;
}

.button  
{
 height:35px;
 background-color: #e0f1ed2e;
 color: white;
 border:none;
 border-radius: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-size: 25px;
   transition: 0.3s;
   font-family: monospace;
 
}

.button:hover 
{
 opacity: 1;
 background-color: coral;

}

a 
{
 text-decoration-line: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

.button_f
{
 height:35px;
 background-color: #e0f1ed2e;
 border:none;
 border-radius: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 font-size: 20px;
    background: #0C3F6F !important; 
    font-family: monospace;
    color:white !important;
}

html {
  color: #bbb;
  font-family: Menlo;
}

.stopwatch {
  font-size: 80px; 
  text-align: center;
}

.results {
  border-color: lime;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
 <!--LINK  CSS STYLESHEET-->
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tic_tac_toe.css">
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

 </head>

 <body>

<embed src="dChanyeol (EXO) & Punch - Stay With Me FMV (Goblin OST Part 1) (Eng Sub + Rom + Han).mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop ="true">

<!--BACKGROUND MUSI
<audio id="myaudio">
  <source src="music.mp3">
</audio>

 JS FOR MUSIC VOLUME
<script>
  var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio").loop=true; 
  audio.volume = 0.2;
  </script>C-->

<div class="stopwatch"></div>
  <ul class="results"></ul>

 <!--CREATE BORD FOR TIC TAC TOE GAME-->
  <table align="center">
   <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="0"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="1"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="2"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="3"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="4"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="5"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="6"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="7"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="8"></td>
   </tr>

   <!--MESSAGE CLASS FOR END GAME-->
    <div class="endgame">
     <div class="text"></div>

     
     <!--BUTTON FOR REPLAY-->
      <button onclick="startGame(), stopwatch.restart();" class="button">Restart</button> <br>
      <!--<button onclick="location.reload();" class="button">Restart New Game</button>-->
      <button class="button_f"><a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/">Share This on Facebook</a></button>
    </div> <!--END MESSAGE-->

  </table> <!--END GAME TABLE BOARD-->
   
 
   <!--LINK JAVASCRIPT-->
  <script src="tic_tac_toe.js"></script>
  

 </body>
</html>
```